# Header not spanning whole page

Tags: php, html, css

**Context:** I am working through a tutorial on PHP with MySQL - currently making a pretend website. HTML/CSS knowledge is assumed in the tutorial, which I don't have.  Everything is going great, except I can't figure out how to make my header span the entire width of the page.

**What I have tried:** First I tried to troubleshoot the issue on my own - I went to the CSS I am using and tried adjusting the 'header' and 'footer' width from 980px to 100% and test it, but no dice. The CSS was a downloadable file in the tutorial, not something I wrote, and 980px is how it was set when I downloaded it. After unsuccessfully tinkering on my own I turned to google, I found this question already asked [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yRV7.png), but the solution was something I had already tried. It is strange because at first in the tutorial, when the tutor ran the webpage - his was only partial page like mine but then all of the sudden in one of the videos his header was spanning the whole page. I checked the exercise files at that point in the video but his CSS file / header /footer page are all identical to mine. I tried to read a bit about the interaction between the CSS and the HTML etc, and I get the general idea but still didn't learn enough to fix my issue.

**Code:**
I have a header/footer .php that I include at the start/end (respectively) of every .php page visible from the browser. Here they are:

Header

```
<?php   if(!isset($page_title)) { $page_title = 'Staff Area'; } ?>

<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">   
  <head>
    <title>GBI - <?php echo h($page_title); ?></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="<?php echo url_for('/stylesheets/staff.css'); ?>" />   
   </head>

  <body>
    <header>
      <h1>GBI Staff Area</h1>
    </header>

    <navigation>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="<?php echo url_for('/staff/index.php'); ?>">Menu</a></li>
      </ul>
    </navigation>
```

Footer

```
<footer>
  &copy; <?php echo date('Y'); ?> Globe Bank
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Selected Portion of my CSS (Recall from above: I have tinkered with width values. h1 block originally didn't have a width value, but I tried that on my own)

```
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 980px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #0055DD;
  color: white;
}

header h1 {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Example of a page where I am loading the header and footer:

```
<?php require_once('../../private/initialize.php'); ?>

<?php $page_title = 'Staff Menu'; ?>
<?php include(SHARED_PATH . '/staff_header.php'); ?>

<div id="content">
    <div id="main-menu">
        <h2>Main Menu</h2>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="<?php echo url_for('/staff/subjects/index.php');?>">Subjects</a></li>
            <li><a href="<?php echo url_for('/staff/pages/index.php');?>">Pages</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</div>

<?php include(SHARED_PATH . '/staff_footer.php'); ?>
```

I understand the above is not exactly what constitutes an MWE, and I apologize for that. Because I am new, I don't know where in my collection of interacting files the problem might be lurking - so I didn't know how to condense it down to an MWE without possibly hiding where the problem was.

**Question:**

> Why does my header not span the whole page?

Will post a screen shot of what it looks like when I run it if anyone would like.

**Edit:** 
Screenshot of the page after loading. This page is the last quoted section of php code above:
[image]

Comment: Can you post the relevant HTML that is produced once the page is loaded? If not, a screenshot would be helpful. Welcome to SO by the way!

Comment: Just an FYI, there isn't a `<navigation>` tag; you want `<nav>`, instead: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/nav

Comment: @TiesonT. i believe he could use `navigation` as an element if it's XML...

Comment: @Anthony As that is a possibility, to match accessibility standards (and since the rest of the code looks like non-XML code) it may still be worth using `<nav>`. [Here's a bit of documentation on why](https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/page-structure/regions/#navigation) for anyone that sees this. `role="navigation"` would work as well [according to WebAIM](https://webaim.org/techniques/aria/#landmarks).

Comment: @ChaseIngebritson i'm just saying it's possible, not necessarily best practice lol:)

Comment: @ChaseIngebritson I updated with a screenshot. Thank you for your welcome. Thank you also for the discussion regarding nav/navigation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `body { width: 100vw; }` or `header { width: 100vw; }` will do the trick. You should only need one or the other.

When you set the width of `header` to `100%`, and the `body` is also set to `100%`, there is no reference point. In other words, `body { width: 100%; }` is 100% of which other element's width? You have to set an "explicit" width, so to speak, somewhere.

`100vh` is similar to `100%` in how it behaves, but `100vh` will ***always*** be 100% of the "browser window" (or rather the viewport width, as Chase Ingebritson has mentioned).

**If none of this works, clear your cache or make sure there are no other CSS dependencies that are interfering with how the page is displayed.**

Comment: Not necessarily 100% of the browser window, but 100% of the viewport. This difference is shown in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34057239/css-vh-units-inside-an-iframe).

Comment: @ChaseIngebritson i know, but i doubt he'd understand the difference...

Comment: Fair, it's not necessarily a beginner's concept. I figured it may be best to clarify though as it could still be an issue. Good answer overall!

Comment: @ChaseIngebritson thanks for mentioning it since it's probably best to at least include that in the answer in case he wants to learn about it

Comment: `width: 100vh` will force a horizontal scrollbar if there is a vertical scrollbar. Not cool.

Comment: @Anthony - you are correct I do not understand the difference. I teach college math and I constantly have to decide whether to give students the 'long technically correct method' or the 'will suffice for now and if they continue to study math it will become apparent at some point'  answer.

Comment: However, I gather from your answer that the first line is an exclusive or - but say I choose to set body width to 100vw, then what should I set header width too?

Comment: @PrinceM if you set the `width` of `body` to `100vw`, you should be able to leave the `width` of `header` at `100%`

Comment: Also - interesting remark about the reference point. I never thought to look up *what* the width percentages were actually percentages *of*. I guess I just defaulted too assuming it was of 'browser window' - but it makes sense, since header div is contained in body div.

Comment: @PrinceM it depends on context (inheritance and stuff like that), but usually it's a percentage of the parent or an ancestor element

Comment: Not yet. I am loading it as we discussed but not seeing a change, so I am just checking file paths etc to make sure I am saving it properly.

Comment: Does it make any difference that I am using the wamp server? Does the version I am using of PHP matter?

Comment: @PrinceM no, those things shouldn't matter at all if you're simply displaying the page in a web browser

Comment: It seems width is completely immune to my changes - I set header width to 60px and got no change. Is there a more global concept that could be restricting these changes?

Comment: @PrinceM you could try `html, body { width: 100vw; }`. if that doesn't work, the issue is clearly somewhere else in your code. you're going to have to go thru a process of a elimination

Comment: I just noticed something in my .CSS style sheet called #content. I remember seeing that in other answers about this type of question - could that be locking my width?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174059/discussion-between-anthony-and-prince-m).

Comment: After some trouble shooting with @Anthony we discovered that in addition to the 100% / 100vw / 100vh component of the answer - we realized that *no* changes to my .CSS file were being registered when I reloaded. Not entirely sure yet, but it seems like the browser was finding another CSS file in my root directory with the same name and loading that. After changing the file name of my .CSS everything functioned properly, thanks for your help Anthony!

Comment: @PrinceM yep np