# CSS: Offset all vh values in the stylesheet by some amount, or take vh from iframe?

Tags: html, css, iframe, height, viewport

I have made a web app, in which i used the viewport height to set the height of many items, now that app has to be loaded in an iframe in another web page; now the problem is that it takes the vh reference not  from the iframe but from the parent page.

is there a way to set the vh based on the iframe itself or can offset all my vh values in that iframe ?

parent webpage:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/view.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/icon.css">
        <script src="js/view.js"></script>
        <script src="js/live-reload.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <div id='splash' class='splash'>
            <img src="img/loader.gif" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="drag" id="drag">
            <div class="window-buttons">
                    <i class="material-icons"  onclick="minWindow();">remove</i>
                    <i class="material-icons"  onclick="maxWindow();">crop_square</i>
                    <i class="material-icons"  onclick="closeWindow();">close</i>
            </div>
        </div>     
        <iframe id='webview' nwfaketop nwdisable/>

    </body>

</html>
```

The thing is the web app loaded in the iframe uses vh all over the place, i dont think it's  a good idea to put all that code here.

Comment: show your code please

Comment: try to set `width/height:100%` to iframe

Comment: @לבנימלכה i tried that, it didnt change

Comment: not much we can do without a jsfiddle or codepen

Comment: possible answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34057239/css-vh-units-inside-an-iframe